# CSS Hover State Boundaries

Tags: html, css

I am very new to coding so I am sorry if this is a simple question. I am trying to fade out the background while fading in the text using hover states.
This code works, however, I cannot seem to figure out why the hover state extends past the red square. I would like the hover state to only work when you mouse over the red square.

```css
.relative{
    position: relative;
  }

  .background {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }

  .text {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    }

  .relative .text{
    transition: 1s;
    color: transparent;
  }

  .relative:hover .text{
    color: lightseagreen;
  }

  .relative:hover .background{
   background: black;
   transition: 1s;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="relative">
    <div class="background"></div>

    <div class="text">Hello</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason is that the relative class is not the same size as the background, to fix this, add

```
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
```

to the relative as well.
Full code below

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .relative{
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }

  .background {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }

  .text {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    }

  .relative .text{
    transition: 1s;
    color: transparent;
  }

  .relative:hover .text{
    color: lightseagreen;
  }

  .relative:hover .background{
   background: black;
   transition: 1s;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="relative">
    <div class="background"></div>

    <div class="text">Hello</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```